# HELP ME com Condição If numa MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, if, textbox

Gente, eu sei que esse site é bem famoso porque a comunidade é SUPER caridosa e gentil.
Me ajudem com essa: eu não to conseguindo fazer com que um MessageBox seja exibido quando eu deixo a minha MaskedTextBox em branco. Eu formatei ela para ficar no padrão de CPF 123.456.789-00 Tô fazendo um formulário pra cadastro. Eu sei fazer pra TextBox normal, mas pra MaskedtTextBox não funciona. O código tá assim:

```
if(txtNome.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha o campo Nome!", "Falta de informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            if(txtCpf.Text == "") // <- Essa é a MaskedTextBox
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha o campo CPF!", "Falta de informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
```

Comment: o segredo é como vc faz a pergunta... tudo que digitou aí poderia ser apenas "maskedtextbox is empty", e então: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757922/4713574

Comment: Muito obrigado, Rovann. Salvou minha noite, cara! Deus te abençoe :D

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários jeitos de verificar se está uma MaskedTextbox está ou não vazia.
Segue o código abaixo que verifica sem erro.

```
            if (maskedTextBox1.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Preencha o campo CPF!", "Falta de informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```